# CORS error after page sits idle for a few minutes

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ajax

Hi I am making an ajax call to a page on the change event of a drop down. When I first load the page it works fine, but if I let the page sit for a few minutes then try to change the dropdown it fails and in the console I see this error (I removed some of the unneeded characters in the query string so it didn't take up so much room). The strange thing is, both of these pages are microsite pages. They also both have security enabled in the properties. I added a bit of SSJS to the AmpScript page being called, but it does not help. Anyone experience this before?

```
Failed to load https://members.s8.exacttarget.com/Content/MicroSites/LoginLandingPage.aspx?rtn=55d8&hub=1: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://pages.mail.salesforce.com' is therefore not allowed access.
page.aspx?QS=330cb:1239 Exception:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the page security in properties to no security for the ajax called page. This seems to be an unfixable issue because the page is trying to redirect back to the login page.